# In react, how to read properties and data from object

Tags: reactjs

I have table component in react which except generic 'Custom Parameters'. The objective is; I pass the object with data and it convert to URL parameter to pass back to API. for example "&startTime=2020-12-12&endTime=2020-12-30"

since this table can be used for any component or object so I need to read property & value dynamically.

now

I have inteface

```
 export interface ISearchCriteriaForm{
    startTime: Date,
    endTime: Date,
    LiveTime: Date,
    schedAction_Active: string,
    siteId: number,
    scheduleId: number
  }
```

In Component I create the instance of ISearchCriteriaForm and assign it a test data.

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const[searchCriteria, setstatusSearchCriteria] = useState<ISearchCriteriaForm> ();


   const searchCriteria : ISearchCriteriaForm= {
     startTime: new Date("08/12/2020"),
     endTime: new Date("09/12/2020"),
     LiveTime: new Date("10/12/2020"),
     schedAction_Active: "Active",
     siteId: 1825,
     scheduleId: 3792
  };

  setEziStatusSearchCriteria(searchCriteria);
```

here I need help. I need to read 'searchCriteria' object property name including value so that I can make final string as below. for example the solution read 'startTime' as property and value '08/12/2020' and so on

```
    "&startTime=08/12/2020&endTime=09/12/2020&LiveTime=10/12/2020&schedAction_Active=Active"
```

Comment: Did you try this `new URLSearchParams(searchCriteria).toString()`?

Comment: What have you tried? Does something like `searchCriteria.startTime` not work for reading the object property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your object to a new instance of `URLSearchParams` like this:

```js
const searchCriteria = {
  startTime: new Date("08/12/2020"),
  endTime: new Date("09/12/2020"),
  LiveTime: new Date("10/12/2020"),
  schedAction_Active: "Active",
  siteId: 1825,
  scheduleId: 3792
};

const res = new URLSearchParams(searchCriteria).toString();
console.log(res);
```

Doesn't work for IE.